Conditionally format specific values within comma-separated values
Is there a way to apply conditional formatting to specific values within a cell of comma-separated values?
  Background

In a Google form, I have a Checkboxes-type question with 50 options that increment by 1, from CACHE 1 to CACHE 50 .
Checkbox Question ( Form )
 

In Google Sheets, each form response combines the selected options in a single column as comma-separated values.
Form Responses ( Spreadsheet )





A
B




1
Timestamp
Check all that apply:


2
9/6/2024 15:59:41
CACHE 1, CACHE 3, CACHE 17, CACHE 29


3
9/6/2024 15:59:45
CACHE 3, CACHE 29


4
9/6/2024 15:59:49
CACHE 1, CACHE 17, CACHE 49, CACHE 50


5
9/6/2024 16:01:10
CACHE 29, CACHE 49




I want to apply conditional formatting to individual options within the comma-separated values but can't figure out how.
Desired Result ( Spreadsheet )




Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.

Not without using a script-based solution, however, there may not be the need.

Best practices encourage us to avoid doing anything to raw form response data but instead use other sheets to manipulate the data as needed.

Conditional formatting rules cannot be applied to parts of a cell, however, the results can be separated into multiple cells and formatting can then be applied.


Variations
A couple of approaches that can be adapted to your needs.
1.  Split to Columns with Formatting
=LET(rng,'Form Responses 1'!A2:B,
   BYROW(FILTER(rng, LEN(INDEX(rng,,1))), LAMBDA(row, 
     TOROW(MAP(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(row)), LAMBDA(col, 
       LET(val,INDEX(row,,col),
         IF(col=2, SPLIT(val,", ",), val)))),1))))

BYROW  COLUMNS  FILTER  IF  INDEX  LAMBDA  LEN  LET  MAP  SEQUENCE  SPLIT  TOROW
 
2.  Character in Options' Column
=INDEX(LET(
  rng,'Form Responses 1'!A2:B,
  cols,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(rng)), optCol,2,
  opts,50, seq,SEQUENCE(1,opts),
  BYROW(FILTER(rng, LEN(INDEX(rng,,1))), LAMBDA(row, 
    { CHOOSECOLS(row, FILTER(cols, cols<optCol)),
      IF(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(row,,optCol), "CACHE "& seq &"\b"), "✔",),
      IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(row, FILTER(cols, cols>optCol))) }))))

BYROW  CHOOSECOLS  COLUMNS  FILTER  IF  IFERROR  INDEX  LAMBDA  LEN  LET  REGEXMATCH  SEQUENCE
 
